# Unable to publish EAR onto Websphere

Tags: java, exception, websphere, ear

I'm running Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software (v. 8.0.4.1) on Windows. I have a EAR project that I'm trying to deploy to my Websphere server running on my machine. The EAR project references a WAR project.

When tying to deploy, I get four messages:

```
Publishing failed
**Could not publish to the server - org.eclipse.wst.server.core**
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publishModules(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.ast.st.v8.core.internal.WASServerBehaviour.publishModules(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Unknown Source)

OK - Unknown

Error in delegate - org.eclipse.wst.server.core
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.etools.webtools.sdo.deploy.internal.cloudscape.DisconnectTaskDelegate.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Publisher.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.executePublishers(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Unknown Source)

deploySuccess -  com.ibm.etools.server.task.ejbdeploy
```

What's weird is that I can see the EAR & WAR services started/synchronized on the server, and when I go into the Admin console, I can see the running application.

Has anyone seen this same errors? Suggestions?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: seems to be a rad bug, have you tried remove the server from rad and add again?

Comment: that did get me past this issue (I had one other problem - sorry for the slow reply!  Thank you!   Was there something specific in the message that showed you the issue?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 12):

Got the same issue. 
removed entries from publish.xml under c:/myworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core for the failing server and also removed the folder tmp* (tmp0 or tmp1 etc whichever applies to failing server).

After restarting the RAD, noticed that these mapping are recreated and the publish seems to work fine.

Comment: This fixed it for me too :) Although I just deleted the tmp directory and restarted RAD. Don't forget to restart RAD as the error didn't go away till I did that. Thanks!

Comment: Same here.  I just deleted the temp directory and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I only removed the tmp* folder from c:/myworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core folder and restarted RSA.

I was then able to publish my EAR onto Websphere 7.0.

No changes were made to publish.xml.

Thank you for the tip!